# i want to change url parameters

Tags: api, url, parameters

hi my url is something like this `abc.domain.com/add/firstname/phone/email` which is api link. i want to change parameters first name,phone,email when user enters in form. please let me know if anyone can help. thanks in advance.
`add/?Client+Name=&Phone+number=&Email+ID=&Partner+ID=AUOVML` i dont want url in this format. format must be as i mentioned in first line. i have done something like this:

```
<form method="get" action="http://abc.domain.com/add/">
  <div class="d-nt-signup">
    <div class="d-nt-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" label="Name*" id="first_name" name="Client Name" active-color='#FB165B' class="d-nt-login-filed">
    </div>
    <div class="d-nt-field-wrap">
      <input type="text" label="Mobile*" id="mobile" name="Phone number" active-color='#FB165B' class="d-nt-login-filed">
    </div>
    <div class="d-nt-field-wrap">
      <input type="email" label="Email*" id="email ID" name="Email ID" active-color='#FB165B' class="d-nt-login-filed">
    </div>
    <div class="d-nt-field-wrap">
      <input type="hidden"  name="Partner ID" value="AUOVML">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do a get request with a form you will get the names and values of the form inputs added to the URL like that. 
You can get around that by using a post request instead. Change `method="get"` to be `method="post"`.

Developers will often handle the result of the form being sent with PHP. Change the action to point to a PHP file, and then in the PHP file you can access the form data through the $_post array like so `$_POST["form_input_name"]`.

See http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php for an example of echoing back data typed into a form.